# How can CakePHP Authorization plugin authorize access to indexes?

Tags: cakephp, authorization, cakephp-3.x

I'm converting my app to CakePHP 3.6, and working now on using the new Authorization plugin. I'm not sure how to check authorization for things like indexes or other reports, where there is no "resource" to pass to the `can()` or `authorize()` functions.

For now, I've built a `ControllerResolver`, loosely copied from the `ORMResolver`, which accepts controller objects and finds policies based on the singularized controller name, so that they're named the same as the Entity policies I'm building. (That is, my `UserPolicy` can have `canIndex` and `canEdit` functions, the former found via the controller and the latter via the entity.)

This works fine in controller actions where I can call `$this->Authorize->authorize($this);`, but it doesn't work in views, where I'd like to be able to do things like:

```
if ($this->Identity->can('index', *something*)) {
    echo $this->Html->link('List', ['action' => 'index']);
}
```

so as to only show links to people who are allowed to run those actions.

Anyone know if there's a reason why the system implicitly requires that the "resource" passed into authorization functions be an object? (For example, the plugin component calls `get_class($resource)` in the case of a failed authorization, without first checking that the provided resource is in fact an object.) Allowing a string (e.g. `\App\Controller\UsersController::class`) would make my life easy. Very happy to put together a PR for this if it's just an oversight.

But authorizing indexes seems like a pretty obvious function, so I wonder if I've missed something. Maybe I'm supposed to pass the table object, and split the authorization between an entity policy and a table policy? But using table objects in views just for this purpose seems like a violation of separation of concerns. Maybe uses of the plugin to date have been things where indexes are always public?

Comment: I don't know the reasoning behind the resource required to be an object, I'm not yet overly familiar with the new plugin, and I'm not sure that I understand what exactly you are trying to authorize on view level, but maybe you could pass the view object (ie `$this`), and in the policy obtain the controller information from the request object that is attached to the view?

Comment: Good thought! I'll give that a go. I've updated the question to include a clearer example of what I can't do right now. Your suggestion would cover that case, but there are still gaps, such as links like that to a different controller than the view is for (a much smaller, but still not empty, subset of my current problem cases) or menu building. I can keep building my menus and links the way I always have, with direct checks of what group(s) the logged-in user is a member of, but that duplicates code between those places and the policies.

Comment: I see... looking at `ResolverInterface::getPolicy()` and `AuthorizationServiceInterface::can()`, I guess you could always implement a resolver that accepts a string for the resource argument, given that for both methods it is typed as `mixed`. Whether that whole thing is a good idea from an architectural perspective, I don't know.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too, and it mostly works, but causes errors if the policy can't be found, because it calls `get_class($resource)`, and `get_class` fails when the input is a string. Like I said, would be an easy PR to fix this, if there's not some good reason why it's how it is.

Comment: Not sure where exactly that call is? One last idea, custom resource objects that can be created from class names, controller instances, request objects, etc., which you could then basically use anywhere, like `$user->can('doSomethingWith', ControllerResource::fromClassName(XyzController::class))`.

Comment: If you can wait a little more I'll fix this problem for you. I've worked a lot on the plugin and I'm right now in the next phase to decouple it from Cake to make it a framework agnostic lib. I agree with your proposal but I have a different way of fixing it in mind. The library already has a collection resolver, you can combine the map and the class resolver - I'm doing right now for you. :) See https://github.com/Phauthentic/authorization

Comment: I've pushed the StringResourceResolver to the repository. Feel free to switch to the library (which is still WIP, it works but I haven't done the middleware yet) or just copy the collection and string resource resolver to your app and use them.

Comment: I can wait days, but probably not weeks. :-) Anything I can do to help it along? Will the eventual resulting updates be pushed back into the existing Cake Authorization plugin repo, or will that be replaced by this, or will the two continue to exist but perhaps diverge?

Comment: I've already done the relevant change ;) You could help if you want with the middleware tests and create "authorization-cakephp" and add the component and view back there. I've removed them from the lib because they're specific to cake. Robert and me have done the same for the authentication plugin already. The chained setters for configs work so much more nice (IMO) than the config arrays cake used. Also we're no longer bound to the stagnating concrete Cake. ;p At least I don't have the plan to port the change back to Cake yet. Feel free to ping me on Slack or Skype if you have questions.

Comment: By the way, the plan for the authentication plugin 2.0 of Cake is to use phauthentic/authentication-cakephp. This might happen with the authorization plugin as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Will dive back into this tomorrow. @ndm, I've edited my question to correct the location of where the offending `get_class` call is; it's in the component, so I guess it doesn't affect the Phauthentic version, and presumably whoever gets to making the Phauthentic/authentication-cakephp version will ensure that's taken care of at that time.

Answer (score 2):

to do this you can use the `authorizeModel`, as stated in the documentation https://github.com/cakephp/authorization/blob/master/docs/Component.md#automatic-authorization-checks. Basically is adding the auhtorizeModel parameters when you load the component at AppController.php

```
$this->loadComponent('Authorization.Authorization', [
    'skipAuthorization' => ['login','token'],
    'authorizeModel' => ['index','add'],
]);
```

When you configure an action to be authorized by model the authorization service uses the TablePolicy, so if you want to authorize the index action for Books you need to create the BooksTablePolicy and implement the method

```
<?php
namespace App\Policy;

use App\Model\Table\BooksTable;
use Authorization\IdentityInterface;

/**
 * Books policy
 */

class BooksTablePolicy
{
    public function scopeIndex($user, $query)
    {
        return $query->where(['Books.user_id' => $user->id]);
    }

    public function canIndex(IdentityInterface $identity)
    {
    // here you can resolve true or false depending of the identity required characteristics
        $identity['can_index']=true;
        return $identity['can_index'];
    }
}
```

This will be validated before the request reaches your controller so you do not need to authorize anything there. Nevertheless if you want to apply an scope policy as you can see in this example:

```
public function index()
{

    $user = $this->request->getAttribute('identity');
    $query = $user->applyScope('index', $this->Books->find()->contain('Users'));
    $this->set('books', $this->paginate($query));
}
```